# Wrapping $.get in another deferred

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-deferred

I'm just trying to get my head around the details of deferred.
Why doesn't the following make the two calls syncronous?

http://jsfiddle.net/JSw5y/889/

**Console output:**
Running ajax get 
Fading in 
Fading in done
 
Finished running ajax get

**Desired output:**
Running ajax get 
Finished running ajax get 
Fading in 
Fading in done

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It doesn't work because in this line:

```
.then(showDiv())
```

you're calling `showDiv` immediately, not passing it as a callback to `.then()`.  It should read:

```
.then(showDiv)
```

Comment: So the solution would be to remove the function call (`()`)?

Comment: @Blender yes, just remove the `()`